# question regarding secret number python game

Tags: python, numbers

I'm wondering what´s happening with my code, because I want to print just in the end if we found the secret number, but I get it every time.

```py
import random

answer = random.randint(1, 101)
user_winner = False
attempts = 0
attempt_word = ""

#Game Loop( the body of the loop inside)
while user_winner != True:
    #User input
    guess = input("Can you guess a number between 1 and 100? ")

    #Check The user Input
    try:
        guess_number = int(guess)
    except:
        print("You should write a number!")
        quit()

    #Increase attempt count
    attempts += 1

    #check the user answer against the secret number
    if guess_number == answer:
        user_winner = True
    elif guess_number > answer:
        print("The number is Smaller!!")
    else:
        print("The number is Bigger!!")

    #Get the spelling of the "attempt" word
    if attempts == 1:
        attempt_word = " attempt"
    else:
        attempt_word = " attempts"

    #Display the result
    print("Congratulations!! You did it in " + str(attempts) + attempt_word)
```

we should not be able to see it (print) unless we get the right result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you try to simulate the code in your loop top to bottom, you will see that the final `print` line is always read at the end, because there's nothing stopping it from reaching that point. You are going to want to either wrap it around a condition (e.g. `if/else`):

```
if user_winner == True:
    print( "Congratulations!! You did it in " + str( attempts ) + attempt_word )
```

You can also consider placing the `print` line under an already existent `if` statement that you wrote:

```
if guess_number == answer:
    print( "Congratulations!! You did it in " + str( attempts ) + attempt_word )
elif ...
```

However, since Python reads it from top to bottom, you would also need to move the block of code you have handling the `attempt_word` variable.

Comment: Thanks Jason, i´ve tried both of your suggestion, but it doesn t work, as i already have done it before, maybe i just need to steep away to see more clear, because im certain that is just a small detail

Comment: Hmm, it works for me, when I tried my first answer. I guessed it in n attempts and the program stopped. What kind of error are you getting? What part of the program is wrong?

Comment: well, was just a matter of spaces,( i didn´t give before print), thanks a lot for the help

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the congratulations part is not in an if statement and so prints every time a number is input. You can either move that up to the first if statement or leave it where it is but put it inside a new if statement.

First solution is you move the congratulations part up to where you first test to see if it's correct like this:

```
#setup
import random
answer = random.randint(1, 101)
user_winner = False
attempts = 0
attempt_word = ""

#Game Loop( the body of the loop inside)

while user_winner != True:

    #User input

    guess = input("Can you guess a number between 1 and 100? ")

    #Check The user Input
    try:
        guess_number = int(guess)
    except:
        print("You should write a number!")
        quit()

    #Increase attempt count
    attempts += 1 

    #check the user answer against the secret number
    if guess_number == answer:
        user_winner = True
        #Get the spelling of the "attempt" word
        if attempts == 1:
            attempt_word = " attempt"
        else:
            attempt_word = " attempts"

        #Display the result
        print("Congratulations!! You did it in " + str(attempts) + attempt_word)
    elif guess_number > answer:
        print("The number is Smaller!!")
    else:
        print("The number is Bigger!!")
```

Or for the second solution you test to see if you get the correct result a second time before printing congratulations like this:

```
#setup
import random
answer = random.randint(1, 101)
user_winner = False
attempts = 0
attempt_word = ""

#Game Loop( the body of the loop inside)

while user_winner != True:

    #User input

    guess = input("Can you guess a number between 1 and 100? ")

    #Check The user Input
    try:
        guess_number = int(guess)
    except:
        print("You should write a number!")
        quit()

    #Increase attempt count
    attempts += 1

    #check the user answer against the secret number
    if guess_number == answer:
        user_winner = True
    elif guess_number > answer:
        print("The number is Smaller!!")
    else:
        print("The number is Bigger!!")

    #Get the spelling of the "attempt" word
    if attempts == 1:
        attempt_word = " attempt"
    else:
        attempt_word = " attempts"

    #Display the result
    if guess_number == answer:
        print("Congratulations!! You did it in " + str(attempts) + attempt_word)
```

Comment: Thank you, i ´ve tried before, and you know what? i didn´t give the space before the print, i just need to go sleep, thanks a lot for the help.